# Always Encrypted Data Validation

Tags: t-sql, always-encrypted, data-validation

Just a question in how could i validate duplicate data's in my database if columns is set to be encrypted(deterministic) in db?

I've tried running the following code, but receive the error below.

```
declare '@test1' varchar(max) = 'XXXXXX'
select * from testing where t1 = '@test1'
```

> Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables '@test1'. The
>   encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type =
>   'PLAINTEXT') and the expression near line '4' expects it to be
>   (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AXS_XXX_CBA_HMAC_SHA_XXX', column_encryption_key_name =
>   'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'XXX') (or weaker).

How can I find the source of this error, or is there another way to determine duplicate rows?

Comment: If the encryption is deterministic then duplicate values should also produce duplicate encrypted values?

Comment: yes they have duplicate value but how could i store it on a temporary table

Comment: Can you please provide the columns you're working with and your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

Deterministic encryption will produce the same value as long as the inputs are the same. In database terms it means that:

> Queries can perform equality comparison on columns encrypted using deterministic encryption, but no other operations (for example, greater/less than, pattern matching using the LIKE operator, or arithmetical operations).

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#feature-details)

So yes you can see if you have duplicates. How? By comparing the stored value of one row with the others in the column.

A theoretical example would be like this:

```
Select EncryptedColumn, COUNT(EncryptedColumn) from yourtable
GROUP BY EncryptedColumn
    HAVING COUNT(EncryptedColumn) > 1
```

This will tell you which values within your `EncryptedColumn` are duplicated. If you can provide the table schema a better example can be given.

Comment: Don’t know why this was downvoted, it is the correct answer

Comment: @Gaius the question is "how" not "is it possible" as far as I can tell - although the OP does leave a lot of information out so I could be wrong there. If the question is "how" then this doesn't answer the question.